# solr exclude a file for indexing

Tags: java, solr, lucene, indexing

I finally got my Solr machine up and running. Indexing local files and network shares works. However I do get an error when indexing a C drive. Post.jar is complaining about pagefile.sys.

Is it possible to exclude a file from indexing? As said above, I'm using the post.jar to index the files.

Comment: is SOLR picking up the files or are you feeding the files? can you share some indexing client code?

Comment: Solr is picking up the files (like crawling). The code I am using is the code of simple post tool (post.jar):[Link to simple post tool](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/util/SimplePostTool.java).

In cmd I use the following command: "java -Dauto -jar -Drecursive=yes post.jar \\192.168.203.142\c\*"

Comment: not sure if exclude feature is available. maybe you should have your own recursive code to find all files and index, excluding the unwanted files

Comment: The \c* would mean it is searching for all the files that start with c, and there is no exclude feature. If it is just 1 or 2 files, you can temporary move the files to another location first, before you start the indexing.